# how to make customised auto increment primary key in mysql

Tags: mysql

I'm not sure if this question is right, but what I really want to know is, how do we make a customized auto-increment in mysql.

I only know when we made an auto-increment for a specific field then it will result as:

```
1,2,3,4,etc
```

What I really want for the outcome is, for example I want the auto-increment format to be like ID-001, then the auto-increment in my specific field will be:

```
ID-001,ID-002,ID-003, ... and so on.
```

Could that be possible?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you really want to store such keys or do you only such a format for the output?

Comment: Actually, could be others. It's just one of the format sample. Basically the normal auto increment would use int right? Perhaps with this such format we could use varchar? cmiiw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can create this mysql view for it. you cab define view something like below.

```
select `table1`.`id` AS `id`,concat('ID-',`table1`.`id`) AS `custom_auto_inc` from `table1`
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that I'm using Yii Framework in addition. I don't know if we can use Yii CRUD for mysql view. Can we?

Comment: mysql view is the similar to tables. So you can write the yii query as like tables. just use the view name in table name place.

Comment: Nice one gowri! Works like a charm.. Thanks